# How to make clang-format keep nested namespaces on the same line?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

Is there an override one could add to `.clang-format` that would make clang-format **not** split nested namespaces declarations into multiple lines one line per namespace (but would keep the formatting for other things like classes and functions as is)? I.e. instead of

`namespace foo {
namespace bar {
...
}
}`

we'd like to have just

`namespace foo { namespace bar {
...
}}`

I have looked at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html but haven't found any obvious setting there.

Comment: I believe this doesn't exist and that using `namespace foo::bar` was recommended on a bug report I read. Off course, your compiler should support this construction

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of clang-format support this setting:

```
CompactNamespaces: true
```

See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html